# Prevent host listener to call two times on div inside label

Tags: html, angular2-directives

I have an div element wrapped with label tag. Label tag has checkbox element. When I get click event value from my directive(by hostListener), my
directive called two times one on div inside label and other for checkbox. How can I call my directive exactly one time.

My directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[home]'
})
export class HomeDirective {
 @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onclick(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
 }
}
```

My html,

```
<div>
 <label for="test">
  <div home>test dataa
   <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
  </div>
 </label>
</div>
```

Output when click on div with home directive:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViAwb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you click on "Test data", this triggers directive click event(1st directive click). This text is part of label. When you click at label, item specified in "for" tag will be clicked( 2nd directive click).

To prevent double firing you should move text from div.

```
<div>
 <label for="test">
   test dataa
   <div home>
   <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
  </div>
 </label>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TyxkmhLlvKszXYarXXvr?p=preview

Comment: Ok! thats work for now. But I have card which flips back on clicking on it and reverts back again clicking it . All my card's data(having image and icons) is inside div and my directive(applied to that div) flip the card by adding flip class on it. Is your solution impact my image and icon's css?

Comment: 1. Please describe behavior that you expecting. 2. Provide all code. How can i say does this change affect something without this? Change of text place should not affect images. But to moved class can be applied different style, depends on css.